# Procedure name with small caps in algorithm2e

Tags: formatting, captions, algorithms, algorithm2e

I know that `procedure` in `algorithm2e` only allows captions like `\caption{ProcedureName()}`.

However, I'd like my procedure to appear in small caps:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[algosection, boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{procedure}

    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
    \Input{Graph $G = (V,E)$}
    \Output{}
    \ForEach{node $v \in V$}
    {
        \lIf{$v$ is marked}{remove $v$}
    }

    \caption{\textsc{removemarked()}}
    \label{alg:removemarked}

\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

Which of course gives error

```
Paragraph ended before \algocf@captname was complete
```

Instead of procedure, if I use `\begin{algorithm} ... \end{algorithm}`, then it forks fine.
Is there a way to make it work in `procedure` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really well documented in `algorithm2e` manual, but to achieve what you want, you have to issue the command

```
\SetProcNameSty{textsc}
```

The argument of `\caption` when using the `procedure` environment can only contain something like `name(arg)`.

In the following MWE I've also added

```
\SetProcArgSty{textsc}
```

just in case you are using procedure captions with arguments:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[algosection, boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetProcNameSty{textsc}
\SetProcArgSty{textsc}

\begin{document}
\begin{procedure}

    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
    \Input{Graph $G = (V,E)$}
    \Output{}
    \ForEach{node $v \in V$}
    {
        \lIf{$v$ is marked}{remove $v$}
    }

    \caption{removemarked()}
    \label{alg:removemarked}

\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]