# How to set the KwProg arg font style with something like `\SetProgSty` in algorithm2e?

Tags: fonts, algorithm2e

I followed some QA links like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218413/308105) in tex stackexchange and use this example tex code:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[algosection, boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetProcNameSty{textbf}
\SetProcArgSty{textbf}
\SetProgSty{textbf}

\begin{document}
\begin{procedure}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{ is}{end}
\Fn{afunc(i: int) : int}{return 0\;}
    \caption{removemarked()}
    \label{alg:removemarked}

\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

I also viewed the [official doc](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf):

> \SetKwProg{Prog}{Title}{ is}{end} Env is a block with ’Title’ (in CapSty style) at the beginning followed by **args in ProgSty** followed by ’is’ then ’text’ inside a block ended by
> ’end’.

In the output pdf, the procedure font has been modified to be bold by `\SetProcNameSty{textbf}` but the KwProg args `afunc(i: int) : int` haven't by changing `ProgSty`:
[image]

One workaround:

Then I tried to directly format the arg text by using `\bfseries`, i.e. `\Fn{\bfseries afunc(i: int) : int}{return 0\;}`, it works as expected.
[image]

Q: How to set the `KwProg` arg font style with something like `\SetProgSty`, e.g. by modifying the default italic with the `textbf` above?

Answer (score 1):

With `\renewcommand{\SetProgSty}[1]{\renewcommand{\ProgSty}[1]{\textnormal{\csname#1\endcsname{##1}}\unskip}}%` added before `\SetProgSty{textbf}`, the problem is solved.

---

Maybe this question is too specific and is not one good question. Then I took some time to reinspect it when it has no replies for some time.

Inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/308105), I viewed the `algorithm2e` code (Sorry for not viewing it when posting. I should think of seeking for the code help when I have programmed for some long time) and found

```tex
\newcommand{\ProgSty}[1]{\textnormal{\emph{#1}}\unskip}%\SetProgSty{emphg} 
\newcommand{\SetProgSty}[1]{\renewcommand{\ArgSty}[1]{\textnormal{\csname#1\endcsname{##1}}\unskip}}%
...
\newcommand{\SetKwProg}[4]{%\SetKwProg{Env}{Title}{is}{end} 
    \algocf@newcmdside@koif{#1}{\KwSty{#2}\ifArgumentEmpty{#2}\relax{\ }\ProgSty{##2}\KwSty{#3}\ifArgumentEmpty{##1}\relax{ ##1}\algocf@block{##3}{#4}{##4}}%
```

Since the `\SetKwProg` use `\ProgSty` but `\SetProgSty` doesn't change it as the code shows, so the original `\SetProgSty` doesn't work. Then I thought of the above solution.

Hope this can help the future readers.